# What is the best way to call MSWord from C++

Tags: c++, ms-word

What is the best way to call MSWord from C++

I never did this before. I always used VB6 and the Word-COM-Library: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OfficeXX\MSWORD.olb`

Respectively:
`Microsoft Word XX.0 Object Library`

1. How should I use/call Word from C++ (VS2010) ?
2. Should I use .NET ? (C++CLI)
3. Do you have a good step by step explanation?

#### Code example in VB

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim mWord    As New Word.Application
    mWord.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim mMaxParagraph  As Long
    Dim aDoc As Word.Document
    Dim aFileName As String
    aFileName = "C:\mydoc.doc"
    Set aDoc = mWord.Documents.Open(aFileName)
    mMaxParagraph = mWord.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    Debug.Print CStr(mMaxParagraph)
    aDoc.Close
    mWord.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you absolutely *have to* use C++? The VB code is easily translated into C#4

Comment: thanks JBRWilkinson. but for now I just want to learn how painful it really is with native C++ and COM.

Answer (score 2):

Doing COM in C++ isn't that painful as long as you're using ATL smart COM pointers.  You simply need to `#import` the type library and this will create a whole bunch of smart pointer classes that you can use in your application.

Comment: Thanks! that sounds good, could you please give a small example how this should look like?

Comment: IIRC `#import <C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OfficeXX\MSWORD.tlb>`. This will generate a number of temporary C++ files with declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Doing COM in native C++ is an exercise in pain. You might be best off using C++/CLI, which gives you all the features of C++ plus the ability to interact with .NET stuff easily.